# WSO2 EMM iOS Server Licensing

Tags: wso2

We are planning to develop MDM solution based on WSO2 EMM.
Since WSO2 EMM is 100% open source and Apache licensed, I hope there is no cost associated with it provided we host and support it.

For iOS platform configuration, the documentation says CSR file needs to be submitted to WSO2 and then WSO2 will send back the signed CSR, P2 repository for enabling the iOS features.

I have an doubt, what is the criteria WSO2 uses for sending back signed WS02. And is there any hidden cost associated with this process.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cost associate with the process. However you will be evaluated before they sending back the signed CSR.